# PHP header 404 .htaccess ErrorDocument not working on local machine (MAMP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mamp

Currently I get a 404 error, but it does not redirect to 404.php

Here are the contents of my index.php:

```
<?
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
exit;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage, but I'd like it to go to 404.php!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is 404.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>404</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page Not Found!</h1>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
    <p>This is my test custom 404 page!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Users/me/folder/mamp/404.php
```

`/Users/me/folder/mamp/404.php` represents the root document folder in MAMP preferences.

I have also tried the relative path of `/404.php` and the URL of `http://localhost:8888/404.php` in .htaccess. So far all the same result, a white page, issuing a 404 but no redirect.

From my reading this all combined should do the trick; still missing something it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `ErrorDocument` is wrong here:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Users/me/folder/mamp/404.php
```

You need to use path either relative path from `DocumentRoot` OR use full URL starting with `http`. So use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

OR

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/404.php
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I have tried the relative `/404.php`, the full DocumentRoot of `/Users/me/folder/mamp/404.php`, and now, at your recommendation, the full URL of `http://localhost:8888/404.php`. All nothing.

Comment: If you enter `http://localhost:8888/404.php` in browser does it show content of `404.php`?

Comment: Ok and are you sure `.htaccess` is enabled? Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Hi, yes that produced a 500 error when I added random text

Comment: It is posted in the question, just one line. Also tested with `RewriteEngine on` above this, but same results

Comment: It is weird. Try this line: `ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry this page is not available"` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Still nothing. Do I need to put anything else in my .htaccess file?

Comment: Just `ErrorDocument` is enough. Did you use `AllowOverride All` in Apache config to enable all the directives in htaccess?